# PropertyType search problems with RESO API

Tags: api, odata, mls

I am using connect-mls RESO API and I am having a problem forming the query to search for via `PropertyType`.

```
http://odata.reso.org/RESO/OData/Property?$filter=/PropertyType/Name eq "Residential"
```

The above query keeps coming up with malformed URI.

I also run into a problem is if try to filter on the `PropertyType` field directly via `$filter=(PropertyType eq 'Residental')` or `$filter=(PropertyType eq 'DE')`.

I get the following error message:

> "message": "StatusCodeError: 400 - {\"error\":{\"code\":null,\"message\":\"The types 'ODataService.PropertyType' and 'Edm.String' are not compatible.\"}}"

Also looked at values in the data dictionary because it seems property type is a enum but have not had any success in any of the formats.

```
http://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW16/Property+Type+Summary
```

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer from another source. For the enums they are in a format of ODataService.PropertyType'DE'. A proper API call example is listed below.

**https://connectmls-api.mredllc.com/reso/odata/Property?$filter=PropertyType eq ODataService.PropertyType'DE'**

For more detailed information on how to properly construct these types of queries, you can look at http://www.odata.org/documentation/